# Automatically generate UI from object

Tags: winforms, binding

My intention here is to automatically create the UI from an object. Thus, instead of creating manually each form, I would pass an object that would generate a generic form display. My plan is to have a class and each property will be shown  on the page. I was thinking to use attributes to control the visual of the control. For instance, (show/hide control), dropdown if property is enum of a foreign key.

I am using C# Winforms.

Comment: yes It's possible, yes you should

Comment: Is there anything provided from Microsoft or should I have to start from scratch?

Comment: It's better you create an empty form. Then create a provider for yourself to create controls from your object

Comment: Yeah but I don't like reinventing t the wheel.

Comment: You can use controls `PropertyGrid` or `DataGridView` which have possibility to generate control based on the type of the datasource. But for the form you need to create your own form which generate labels/textboxes or else based on the type

Comment: Not necessarily.
The plan is to write a generic helper method that generates a view by using reflection.

Comment: Could you just extend Form and pass a class object as a constructor parameter?

Comment: Your edit removed any hint of a question.  Look at the InitializeComponent code a form generates in the designer file — you would follow that construction in your classes.